# Excel GoalSeek Macro Not working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Anyone have any advice on how to fix this macro. A compile error keeps coming up highlighting the offset function and saying sub or function not defined.

```
Worksheets("Testing").Range(Offset(K51, 0, C41)).GoalSeek _
Goal:=0, _
ChangingCell:=Worksheets("Testing").Range(L58)
```

Comment: `Offset` uses 2 arguments, not 3.

Comment: How would I fix offset? Basically just want to pick a cell that is (c41) spots right of K51

Comment: Also, I believe Offset uses 3 arguments

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel

Answer (score 1):

You are not using properly the `Offset` function.

> From MS Website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel

```
expression . Offset( RowOffset , ColumnOffset )
```

Example

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=3).Activate
```

Comment: What is the active cell?

Comment: `ActiveCell` refers to the Cell Active (Selected or with focus). You can modify to `Offset` work with a Specific `Cell` or `Range`.